# Redux persist, data not persisting

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-persist

I am using `redux-persist`, my data is persisting, but is overwritten by the `VIDEOS_SUCCESS` when my app is launched. How can I prevent this and persist my data?

reducer:

```
case "VIDEOS_SUCCESS": {
    const { data } = action;
    let videos = [];
    let questions = [];
    data.map(item => {
        const {
            id,
            title: { rendered: title },
            content: { rendered: description },
            youtubeVideo,
            ...
            icon
        } = item;

        const newVideo = {
            id,
            title,
            preview: trimText(description, 100),
            description,
            youtubeVideo,
            bookMarked: false,
            ...
            current: 0,
            correctScore: 5,
            totalScore: 50,
            results: {
                score: 0,
                correctAnswers: 0
            },
            completed: false,
            icon
        };

        videos.push(newVideo);
    });

    return videos;
}
```

Store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer, autoRehydrate } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import logger from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    storage: storage, 
    whitelist: ["videos"],
    timeout: null
};

const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(pReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default store;
```

App:

```
import { store, persistor } from "./config/configureStore";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import AppNavigator from "./navigation/AppNavigator";
import NavigationService from "./navigation/actions";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("./assets/images/TC_background.jpg")}
        style={styles.container}
      >
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <AppNavigator
              ref={navigatorRef => {
                NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
              }}
            />
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

I fetch my data from my default route:

```
import DrawerHeader from "../navigation/DrawerHeader";
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchData } = this.props;
    fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    const { videos } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <HomeMenu {...this.props} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchData())
});
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    videos: state.videos
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HomeScreen);
```

My rehydrate is working, but the `VIDEO_SUCCESS` nextState shows initial fetch data.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest version of redux-persist there is no need to do this.
As Rehydrate() is called automatically as long as you are persisting state(root reducer).

```
case "persist/REHYDRATE": {
    if (action && action.payload) {
        const {
            payload: { videos }
        } = action;
        return videos;
    }

    return [];
```

But make sure that your app is wrapped with a persistGate.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootComponent />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Transforms allow you to customize the state object that gets persisted and rehydrated.
Look at [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) docs, if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question, my data does persist but the initial fetch when my app launches - the data gets overwritten. How can i prevent this?

Comment: Sorry to just comeback after a year. Are you still stuck with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this line.

```
// check if state exists from persist, and return, otherwise fetch from
if (Array.isArray(state) && state.length > 0) {
    return state;
}
```